# Hypothesis test of a sample that contains both male and female.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

If I want to do a hypothesis test of a sample that contain $49$ women and $51$ men. The hypothesis test is only regarding the women which has a given sample standard deviation of $12,032$ and sample mean of $13,633$.

Do I just ignore the fact that my sample includes men and just go with the number of women and their data or should I do some kind of binominal calculation?

Answer (score 2):

The hypothesis test is only on women. So, you can go with the number of women and their data alone.